# Why does my Set to List conversion throw a null pointer exception?

Tags: java, arraylist, nullpointerexception, set

```
Set<String> something = null;
List<String> = new ArrayList<>(something);
```

This code throws a `NullPointerException`. Is there any better way to make this conversion?

Comment: You can't convert null to something else you can assign null to something...

Comment: You explicitly set `something` to `null`. What did you expect?

Comment: If something is going to be null, you might as well simple new up empty the List<string>, what is the point of trying to convert something null?

Answer (score 2):

The [Javadoc specifies](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList(java.util.Collection)) that it will `NullPointerException`, because it's trying to convert a collection that doesn't exist into an `ArrayList`.

> public `ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c)`
>
> Constructs a list containing the elements of the specified collection, in the order they are returned by the collection's iterator.
>
> Parameters:
>
> - `c` - the collection whose elements are to be placed into this list
>
> Throws:
>
> - `NullPointerException` - if the specified collection is `null`

---

Why don't you actually make a `Set` object? Try:

```
Set<String> something = new HashSet<>();
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>(something);
```

If you would prefer to make an empty list when `something` is `null`, try:

```
List<String> stringList =
         something == null ? new ArrayList<>() : new ArrayList<>(something);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're expecting the list to be null when the set is null, try:

```
Set<String> something = //Something..... either null or not null
List<String> somethingList = something == null ? null : new ArrayList<>(something);
```

The reason for the null pointer exception is that the `ArrayList(Collection<? extends T> collection)` constructor (the one you're calling) tries to iterate over the passed in collection. As that collection is null, you're of course going to hit a null pointer.

Comment: "The reason" is [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList(java.util.Collection)) which states "*NullPointerException - if the specified collection is null*". It is perfectly possible to do a null check on a method parameter and not throw an exception. In this case they chose to throw an exception, and it is documented as such.